# With pre-commit hook getting "E0000 Template needs to be an object."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, lint

*cfn-lint version: 0.53.0*

*Description of issue.*

I have following setup on my Ubuntu machine

> 1. cfn-lint
> 2. cfn-python-lint via pre-commit

**Case 1**: If I run `cfn-lint ./**/*.yml` from terminal at the project root folder then there are no errors

**Case 2**: If I now try to git commit the code with pre-commit installed, it gives the following error "E0000 Template needs to be an object." for the parameters JSON file.

The parameter JSON looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "XKey",
    "ParameterValue": "XValue"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "YKey",
    "ParameterValue": "YValue"
  },
 ..
 ..
 ..
 ..
]
```

And the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` files looks like

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-added-large-files
    -   id: pretty-format-json
        args:
            - --autofix
-   repo: https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint
    rev: v0.53.0
    hooks:
    -   id: cfn-python-lint
        files: ./.*\.(json|yml|yaml)$
```

Comment: Could you send your whole JSON file, zipped or something? Or not?

Comment: E0000 doesn't necessarily mean Template needs to be an object (although it may).  E0000 occurs whenever your template failed to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case 1, you are only matching files with a `*.yml` extension and not a JSON extension. However, in Case 2, being your pre-commit hook, you do include json files as well. Meaning it will probably try to interpret your parameters JSON file as a CloudFormation file.

Your parameters file isn't CloudFormation however, it is a simple JSON array containing some values. A CloudFormation file is always an object, never an array at the top level. This would explain the error message. The solution: only include files in your cfn-python-lint scan that are actually CloudFormation files.